# With CSS Grids, is there a way to wrap the implicit grid when using grid-auto-flow: column?

Tags: javascript, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to implement a layout with a 4x2 grid that flows (using `grid-auto-flow: column`) into a second 4x2 grid underneath. In essence, I'm trying to cut an 8x2 grid in half and laying the two halves one on top of the other. Is there a way to have this layout wrap around on itself?

[image: What I'm trying to achieve.]

So far, my grid is laid out with

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

And the child nodes are broken into 3 classes: small, medium, and large

```css
.c-small { }

.c-medium {
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.c-large {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

Is there a way for me to wrap the implicit grid around to the bottom instead of smashing it up against the right-hand side of the grid?

I'm not sure what I'm attempting even possible at all without JS. (Right now I'm contemplating a solution where I manually move items from one grid to a separate second grid when they overflow, but I don't know of a means of checking whether a grid item has overflowed into the implicit grid.)

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/bdnk/pen/aVxBRd/)

```js
// VARS
var count = 0;

// HELPERS
function grab(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

// GRIDS
var grid1 = {
  spaceLeft: 8,
  add: function(size) {
    switch (size) {
      case 'S':
        this.addToBack(createEmptySmall())
        break;
      case 'M':
        this.addToBack(createEmptyMedium())
        break;
      case 'L':
        this.addToBack(createEmptyLarge())
        break;
      default:
    }
  },
  prep: function(elem) {
    // if (elem === undefined) { break; }

    switch (elem.getAttribute('size')) {
      case "S":
        this.spaceLeft -= 1;
        break;
      case "M":
        this.spaceLeft -= 2;
        break;
      case "L":
        this.spaceLeft -= 4;
        break;
      default:
    }
    
    return elem;
  },

  addToFront: function(elem) {
    elem = this.prep(elem);
    addToFront(grab('js-grid1'), elem);
  },

  addToBack: function(elem) {
    elem = this.prep(elem);
    addToBack(grab('js-grid1'), elem);
  },
}

var grid2 = {
  spaceLeft: 8,
  addToFront: function(elem) {
    if (elem === undefined) {
      elem = createEmptyMedium()
    }
    // switch (elem.getAttribute('size')) {
    //   case "S":
    //     this.spaceLeft -= 1;
    //     break;
    //   case "M":
    //     this.spaceLeft -= 2;
    //     break;
    //   case "L":
    //     this.spaceLeft -= 4;
    //     break;
    //   default:
    //
    // }
    addToFront(grab('js-grid2'), elem);
  }
}

//METHODS
function createEmptySmall() {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("a-grid__item", "c-small");
  elem.setAttribute('size', "S");
  count++;
  elem.innerHTML = count.toString();

  return elem;
}

function createEmptyMedium() {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("a-grid__item", "c-medium");
  elem.setAttribute('size', "M");
  count++;
  elem.innerHTML = count.toString();

  return elem;
}

function createEmptyLarge() {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("a-grid__item", "c-large");
  elem.setAttribute('size', "L");
  count++;
  elem.innerHTML = count.toString();

  return elem;
}

function addToFront(grid, elem) {
  grid.insertBefore(elem, grid.childNodes[0]);
}

function addToBack(grid, elem) {
  grid.appendChild(elem, grid.childNodes[0]);
}

function shift() {
  var elem = grab('js-grid1').lastElementChild;
  grid2.addToFront(elem);
}

function changeSize(elem, size) {
  console.log('hit');
  if (size === undefined) {
    switch (elem.getAttribute('size')) {
      case "S":
        size = "M"
        break;
      case "M":
        size = "L"
        break;
      case "L":
        size = "S"
        break;
      default:
        size = "M";
    }
  }

  if (size == "S" || size == "M" || size == "L") {
    elem.setAttribute('size', size);

    switch (elem.getAttribute('size')) {
      case "S":
        elem.className = "a-grid__item c-small"
        break;
      case "M":
        elem.className = "a-grid__item c-medium"
        break;
      case "L":
        elem.className = "a-grid__item c-large"
        break;
      default:

    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* OVERRIDES */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: inherit !important;
}

/* LAYOUTS */
.l-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.l-grid {
  height: calc(50vh - 70px - 32px);
  /* 100vh */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding: 16px;
}

.l-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

/* ATOMS */
.a-grid__item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* height: 200px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* COMPONENTS */
.c-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin: 16px 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}

.c-small {
  /* auto */
}

.c-medium {
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.c-large {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-title">
  CSS Grids
</div>
<div class="l-canvas">
  <div id="js-grid1" class="l-grid">
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="js-grid2" class="l-grid">
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-large" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium" onclick="changeSize(this)">
      8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Codepen [added](https://codepen.io/bdnk/pen/aVxBRd)

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to merge `#js-grid1` and `#js-grid2` into one element but retain the layout from your picture/codepen?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to achieve a dynamic layout where grid items that overflow from the top are moved to the bottom. I've gotten as close as I can with two separate grids, but the catch here is that I have to manually shift the grid items from one grid to the other, and I can't tell if there's a way to know if a grid item has overflowed or not.

Comment: So combining all items into one grid container isn't an option?

Comment: The idea was to have it wrap across two lines. If there's a way for me to do that and have everything in one grid container, that'd be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to hide all overflow elements from grids. I've changed styles for grid for this.

```css
.l-grid {
  height: calc(50vh - 70px - 32px);
  display: grid;
  /* fixed percentage minus (n-1)/n * column gap, n is column count */
  /* with calc to include gaps instead of flexible fr units */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 12px));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  /* set auto generated column width to 0 */ 
  grid-auto-columns: 0;
  /* hide when overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

In JavaScript I've I've added function `changeSize` to change size based on CSS class.

Then I've added function `isHidden` to calculate if grid item is hidden based coordinate of right side (because two-column items can be cropped when overflow).

And finally `moveHiddenElementsToNextGrid` function restores original layout and moves invisible items to second grid.

```js
$(".a-grid__item").click(function() {
  var $gridItem = $(this);
  changeSize($gridItem);
  moveHiddenElementsToNextGrid();
});

function changeSize($gridItem) {
  if ($gridItem.hasClass("c-small")) {
    $gridItem.removeClass("c-small");
    $gridItem.addClass("c-medium");
  } else if ($gridItem.hasClass("c-medium")) {
    $gridItem.removeClass("c-medium");
    $gridItem.addClass("c-large");
  } else if ($gridItem.hasClass("c-large")) {
    $gridItem.removeClass("c-large");
    $gridItem.addClass("c-small");
  }
}

function isHidden($gridItem) {
    var elementRight = $gridItem.position().left + $gridItem.width();
    var parentWidth = $gridItem.parent().width();
    var parentMarginRight = parseInt($gridItem.parent().css("margin-right"));
    return elementRight - parentWidth > parentMarginRight;
};

function moveHiddenElementsToNextGrid() {
  $(".a-grid__item").appendTo("#js-grid1");
  $(".a-grid__item").filter(function() { return isHidden($(this)); }).appendTo("#js-grid2");
}

moveHiddenElementsToNextGrid();
```

```css
/* OVERRIDES */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/* LAYOUTS */

.l-canvas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.l-grid {
  height: calc(50vh - 70px - 32px);
  /* 100vh */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 12px));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: 16px;
}

.l-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
}


/* ATOMS */

.a-grid__item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* height: 200px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-width: 0;
}


/* COMPONENTS */

.c-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin: 16px 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}

.c-small {
  /* auto */
}

.c-medium {
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.c-large {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c-title">
  CSS Grids
</div>
<div class="l-canvas">
  <div id="js-grid1" class="l-grid">
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-small">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-large">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="a-grid__item c-medium">
      8
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="js-grid2" class="l-grid">
  </div>
</div>
```